# Shell script file (.sh) does not run, and throws an error

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am new to Linux, and I have a shell script (`.sh`) file I on my Desktop that I want to run.

This is the content of the `test.sh` file on my `Desktop` directory:

```
#!bin/bash
#test.sh
echo "test"
```

I want to run (execute) `test.sh` through the terminal. These are the commands that I'm using:

```
cd Desktop
```

I give permission to run `test.sh` with:

```
chmod +x test.sh
```

and then try to open the file:

```
test.sh
```

But I get this error:

```
test.sh: command not found
```

and when I enter `test.sh` with `./`, I again get this error:

```
bash: ./test.sh: bin/bash: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> ```
> bash: ./test.sh: bin/bash: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
> ```

Replace:

```
#!bin/bash
```

With:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

`bin/bash` is a path relative to the current directory.  `/bin/bash` is an absolute path that works whatever the current directory is.

Also, have a look at your PATH:

```
echo $PATH
```

If you place `test.sh` in any directory listed there and you will will be able to execute  it without the `./` or other path specifier.  Many people create a `$HOME/bin` directory, place all their scripts there, and add it to their PATH.

Comment: Khoda Pedar Madarat ra biamorzad (I mean God Bless you And your parents)

Answer (score 3):

To be able to run your bash script, change first line to

```
#!/bin/bash
```

That is the binary that will interpret and run your script.

To run a bash script, do the following

```
./scriptname.sh
```

In your example:

```
./test.sh
```

in the directory where you have the script.

Answer (score 1):

I edited the .sh file on a Windows machine and saw similar issue. The issue was fixed after running `dos2unix` on the script.

Answer (score 0):

### I had the same problem

`zsh: not a directory: ./tst.sh`

[image]

### my solution ✅

> git diff

```sh
- #!/usr/bin/env/ bash
+ #!/usr/bin/env bash
```

[image]
[image]

### conclusion

```sh
# ✅
#!/usr/bin/env bash


# ❌ without `/` beginning of the path
#!usr/bin/env bash


# ❌ with `/` end of the path
#!/usr/bin/env/ bash
```